# Gemfire Partitioning and Partition region key

Tags: gemfire

With reference to the answer to the question posted on link
[How gemfire does colocation of replicated and partitioned regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677584/how-gemfire-does-colocation-of-replicated-and-partitioned-regions?s=1|1.2435)

Please confirm if my understanding on the reply is correct
1) In case we have 3 Partition regions which are co-located as below
  Customer (central region)
     Order (co-located with Customer)
     Invoice (co-located with Customer)

Customer region - key - String -"customerId"
Order region - key - String - "orderId_customerId"
Invoice region - key -String - "invoicenum_customerId"

Now in Partition resolver for Order and Invoice region we need to derive fom the the key customerId part using string operation and pass the customerId as the routing key.

Is this understanding correct?
This should enable data co-location and these regions data can be saved as part of a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The PartitionResolver should extract the customer id part of the key, and that will make all of the entries with that same customer id reside on the same member.